# C# - System.BadImageFormatException System.Security

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, 64-bit

Firstly, sorry for my English.

We have an application running in a lot of clients, x64, x86 without problems. But in one specially occurs the exception above in one event. We tried reinstall the application and reinstall Framework 4.0, wich our application uses. I guess that is a simple issue but we can't find the solution. We also tried restore Windows, no success. The assembly is the same from "c:/windows/assembly". Windows is x64.

***Message | Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module should contain an assembly manifest.***

Comment: It seems that your program is using a component compiled for an older version of the fw. From the message you get I think you need to install .net fw 2.0 in that station.

Comment: Thank's @E-Bat, I will try.